# itext skipFirstFooter skipLastHeader incorrect behavior

Tags: java, itext

Hello everybody I need some helpe with iText PdfPTable

there is a small code snippet

```
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.setHeaderRows(2);
    table.setFooterRows(1);
    table.addCell(getContinuedCell(CONTINUED_FROM_NEXT_PAGE));
    table.addCell(getContinuedCell(CONTINUED_ON_NEXT_PAGE));
    table.setSkipFirstHeader(true);
    table.setSkipLastFooter(true);
```

But this code have unexpected behavior - if I set setSkipFirstHeader(true), first footer have incorrect height calculation. There is small image with case 1:

```
![PdfPTable two problems][1]
```

[image]

My tables is putted into cell with red border. CONTINUED_ON_NEXT_PAGE string printed outside red border. If I will set skipFirstHeader(false), all will be ok. But I can't do this, because I need CONTINUED_FROM_NEXT_PAGE only on next page. Think it is depend from

```
        table.setHeaderRows(2);
        table.setFooterRows(1);
```

because footer it is a part of header (lol).
If anybody know solution, please help, I will be glad to see any response.

and one more thing - there is a case 2. Can I fit table for all parent cell height? Or there is exist more elegant solution 'for continous from next page'?

Comment: Please tell us which version of iText you are using. Also please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). The `setSkipFirstHeader()`/`setSkipLastFooter()` methods are tested in the [SimpleTable5](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/SimpleTable5) example and as far as I can see, the functionality works correctly: [simple_table5.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/simple_table5.pdf)

Comment: No, this does not work on this example too. There is different bottom padding on first page and on second page. You can see it if you will do that one

Comment: document.newPage();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Table XYZ (Continued)"));
        cell.setColspan(5);
        table.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Continue on next page"));
        cell.setColspan(5);
        table.addCell(cell);
        table.setHeaderRows(2);
        table.setFooterRows(1);
        table.setSkipFirstHeader(true);
        table.setSkipLastFooter(true);

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 350; i++) {
            table.addCell(String.valueOf(i+1));
        }
        PdfPTable outerTable = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell dCell = outerTable.getDefaultCell();
        dCell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
        dCell.setBorderWidth(1);
        dCell.setBorderColor(BaseColor.CYAN);
        outerTable.addCell(table);
        document.add(outerTable);

Comment: Sorry, I can't format code in comments. This is example table code with outer wrapper table.

Comment: Itext 5.5.0. But also I try 5.5.5, result the same

Comment: You're not supposed to nest tables with repeating headers/footers. It's the first one I see some one doing this. I won't look into this. If you want somebody to fix this, please post a ticket on https://jira.itextsupport.com/ If you do not have an account, ask the person who is responsible for licensing at your company to get one.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I work with code in com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText (2.1.7) and fix almost everything with table's rendering. Also, I saw last changes in itext, and I can say, that there nothing was fixed, but some weird hacks added. At first there is incorrect check's for footer and header rendering, and when I fix this bug, I rewrite a lot of code in goComposite() method. Also, in PdfPRow::splitRow method weird hack was added -  bottom + 0.00001f; this is poor attempt to fix split row's height on page break. Why somebody do it? Because somebody don't calculate table borders on top and bottom.

Comment: I make a lot of  changes, and, if you want, I can show repo with my fixes.

Comment: Contributions are usually done through github: https://github.com/itext iText 2.1.7 is no longer supported; there is no way to contribute to that 5 year old version.